# Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server' in R on MacOS (CPU M2)

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, dbi

On a MacOS Ventura with a Apple Silicon M2 CPU, I have installed the  Microsoft ODBC driver 18 for SQL Server following the instructions provided by Microsoft at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/install-microsoft-odbc-driver-sql-server-macos

When using standard DBI connection string in R:

```
db <- config::get("localhost")
conn <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),
                       Driver   = "ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server",
                       Server   = "localhost",
                       UID      = db$uid,
                       PWD      = db$pwd,
                       Port     = 1433,
                       Database = db$database
```

When running this code I get the following error:

Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server' : file not found

I have the feeling that this indicates that there is something wrong with the connection between my R and the driver register in macOS. Unfortunately, I have not been able to identify how to correct the problem.

Does anybody have experience with this and can advise me on how to connect?

I appreciate your assistance!

Comment: Did you previously have Driver 17 working and this was an upgrade? Or is this a first-time use of ODBC for sql server?

Comment: @r2evans-GONAVYBEATARMY First time installation on this machine (and on a macOS for me).

Comment: Did you install `odbc` per [its documentation](https://r-dbi.github.io/odbc/#macos)? Installing the R package alone is not sufficient, you also need underlying OS packages (notably `unixodbc`).

Comment: Yes I went over the `odic` and `unixodbc`  installation and the others again, but so no luck :-(

Comment: this happened to me .It happens that the os image i was running came with preinstalled msodbc17 that it some how defaulted to. so a solution is to try uninstalling msodbc17 and everything should work. just incase get the output of `odbcinst -j` and check the `DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini` to see which version is installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may just be that your install path isn't where R is looking. In [the Rstudio docs](https://solutions.posit.co/connections/db/best-practices/drivers/), it's advised one can add the odbc driver path to .Renviron.

I found simply adding this was sufficient to resolve the issue:

```
# in ~/.Renviron
ODBCSYSINI=/opt/homebrew/etc
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
odbcinst -j
```

Then you will see:

```
unixODBC 2.3.4
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /Users/emehex/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

Please check your ODBC version in /etc/odbcinst.ini (you should see):

```
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
Driver=/usr/local/lib/libmsodbcsql.17.dylib
UsageCount=1
```

if not, please upgrade to ODBC Driver 18